# How did SourceForge maim this Unicode character?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

A little encoding puzzle for you.

A comment on a SourceForge tracker item contains the character [U+2014](http://tools.scarfboy.com/unicode.html?s=U%2B2014), EM DASH, which is rendered by the web interface as `—` like it should.

In the XML export, however, it shows up as:

```
&#226;&#8364;&#8221;
```

Decoding the entities, that results in these code points:

```
U+00E2 U+20AC U+201D
```

I.e. the characters `â€”`. The XML should have been `&#8212;`, the decimal representation of 0x2014, so this is probably a bug in the SF.net exporter.

Now I'm looking to reverse the process, but I can't find a way to get the above output from this Unicode character, no matter what erroneous encoding/decoding sequence I try. Any idea what happened here and how to reverse the process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The the XML output is incorrectly been encoded using CP1252. To revert this, convert `â€”` to bytes using CP1252 encoding and then convert those bytes back to string/char using UTF-8 encoding.

Java based evidence:

```
String s = "â€”";
System.out.println(new String(s.getBytes("CP1252"), "UTF-8")); // —
```

*Note that this assumes that the stdout console uses by itself UTF-8 to display the character.*

Comment: Python based evidence: `u'\u2014'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')` indeed gives `u'\xe2\u20ac\u201d'`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In .Net, `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes("â€”"))` returns `—`.

SourceForge converted it to UTF8, interpreted the each of the bytes as characters in CP1252, then saved the characters as three separate entities using the actual Unicode codepoints for those characters.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't check out. The UTF-8 encoding of the dash is three bytes, but the decoded entities are bigger than that. Python: `u'\u2014'.encode('utf-8')` gives `'\xe2\x80\x94'` and I don't see how you get from there to the three codepoints I mentioned above.

Comment: @Thomas: In .Net, `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("—")).Select(c => (int)c)` returns your code points.  See my edit.

Comment: Note that the original answer used `Encoding.Default`.